# How to transform a table into text file in file operation?

Tags: c

I'm new to file operation and I want to insert data from this table into a text file. How can I do it?

Let's say if my table is in below:

| Deal & Promotion | Option | Detail | Card Price (include initial store value) | Reload | Total Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My30 | - | 30 days | - | 30 | 30 |
| MyCity | 1 day | Reload | - | 5 | 5 |
| MyCity | 1 day | First time | 10 | 5 | 15 |
| MyCity | 3 days | Reload | - | 15 | 15 |
| MyCity | 3 days | First time | 10 | 15 | 25 |
| Concession Card | Student | Fare discount 50% | 15 | (user define values) | Minimum reload: 15(user define values) |
| Concession Card | Senior Citizen | Fare discount 50% | 15 | (user define values) | Minimum reload: 15(user define values) |
| Concession Card | Disability | Fare discount 50% | 15 | (user define values) | Minimum reload: 15(user define values) |

Let say if I want to transform all of them to a text file like this:

```
FILE *input;
    input = fopen("pricelist.txt","w");
    fprintf(input,"My30 30Days FirstTime&Reload 30.00\nMyCity 1Day Reload 5.00\nMyCity 1Day FirstTime 15.00\nMyCity 3Days Reload 15.00\nMyCity 3Days FirstTime 25.00\nConcessionCard Student Benefit50%% >=15.00\nConcessionCard SeniorCitizen Benefit50%% >=15.00\nConcessionCard OKU Benefit50%% >=15.00");
    fclose(input);
```

The example text file that I have build is like this:
[image: text file]
I cannot enter spacing for 2 words so I stick them together. Is there any other way to insert those data similar to the table above?

After transforming all the data into the text file how can I call or passing these data or values in my coding later on?

Comment: You have many options.  You could store the file as CSV, but then you need to worry about either prohibiting the use of the separator in the fields, or deal with escaping the separator.  You could store everything as a fixed width field.  You could use a well known serialization method.  Or....choose some other method to store the data.  The choice is yours to make.

Comment: Do you really _want_ a text file? I'm asking because there are several options where you don't have to deal with direct file access, for example by using an SQLite database.

Comment: Please show us an example how the resulting text file should look like.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a serialization and deserialization method in your program so that when you write or read the text file, it will keep the table format.

Serialization: You will write the file, in a specific order, using separators in the middle of the values.

Deserialization: You will read the file, detecting the separators dinamically, and assigning the values, in the same order you wrote them, to a matrix.